# Failed to install Laravel PHP Framework using "composer install" on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04

I install Laravel via Download as indicated on http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) was already installed. But when I ran `composer install` to install all of the framework's dependencies, I got the following messages and errors:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

> The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or
>   service not known failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known https://packagist.org
>   could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the
>   local cache and may be out of date

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "https://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$b34cfb140404adf89817de230d9257048baa3d027e56a98d9ae5d089f7f92596.json"
>   file could not be downloaded: php_netw   ork_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known   failed to open stream:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known

```
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Any thoughts about this? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** It works well on Laravel 5.0. I'm working on the 4.2. I don't know if it's the composer.phar issue or the server issue? Its just fine on Windows 8.1 with XAMPP 5.6.3 (PHP: 5.6.3) installed.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps
1.Download the zip file from [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)

2.Extract the contents of zip file into a directory

3.Use cd to go into ur directory where u extracted the files

4. From terminal run `composer update`
5. After composer finishes updating the dependency run `composer dump-autoload`

Hope this helps

Comment: That works well on Laravel 5.0. I'm working on the 4.2. I don't know if it's the composer.phar issue or the server issue? Its just fine on Windows 8.1 with XAMPP 5.6.3 (PHP: 5.6.3) installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this:

```
composer update
```

in your laravel folder. Then it will download all the packages define in the composer.json file. See, if that helps.

Comment: Download laravel zip from https://github.com/laravel/laravel and then go in the directory through terminal and try doing composer update.

Comment: I think that's a 5.0 version. All works well with that version but I'm working on the 4.2.

Comment: I too work on 4.2, and this procedure works fine. Maybe it would be composer.phar issue.

Comment: By the way, Laravel 4.2 version installation via composer works well on Windows 8.1 with XAMPP 5.6.3 (PHP: 5.6.3) installed.

Comment: Great! gonna try this on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the basics. First check your internet connection. The downloads fail when your connectivity breaks. `https://packagist.org/packages.json` is an online resource, so the first reason why this can happen is bad or unstable internet connection. You might want to try with a different source of internet.